# How to intialize an array of functions in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have to keep on adding values to an array of functions `undoSteps`

```
let undoSteps: [() => void] = [null];
undoSteps.push(printingSomething());
```

This adds one more entry of null in the array.

How can get away with the *null* without using shift() method ?

Comment: Why can't you use shift? Why does the array have to start with a null element?

Comment: isn't `let undoSteps: Array<Function> = [];` doing the job? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize it as empty (also the type is off, you define it as a tuple with one element, essentially):

```
let undoSteps: (() => void)[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in the code you are providing, is defining a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), which is a set of elements with defined type, order, and amount (it actually does not differ from a normal array on runtime).

As H.B. said, this is the correct syntax for what you are trying to achieve.

```js
let undoSteps: (() => void)[] = [];

// if printingSomething() returns a function, this is correct
undoSteps.push(printingSomething());
```

or

```js
let undoSteps: Array<() => void> = [];

// if printingSomething() returns a function, this is correct
undoSteps.push(printingSomething());
```

But if you do not foresee to set a specific set of parameters for the functions or specific return type (different from `void` or `undefined`), you can write it by using a generic function type:

```js
let undoSteps: Function[] = [];
```

or

```js
let undoSteps: Array<Function> = [];
```